# Python - Why is this code considered a generator?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, generator

I have a list called 'mb', its format is:

```
['Company Name', 'Rep', Mth 1 Calls, Mth 1 Inv Totals, Mth 1 Inv Vol, Mth 2
```

...And so on

In the below code I simply append a new list of 38 0's.  This is fine.

However in the next line I get an error:
'generator' object does not support item assignment

Can anyone tell me:
1) how to correct this error, and
2) why len(mb)-1 below is considered a generator.

Note:  row[0] is merely a 'Company Name' held in another list.

```
mb.append(0 for x in range(38))
mb[len(mb)-1][0]=row[0]
```

Comment: To make your code neater, note that `mb[len(mb)-1] == mb[-1]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In fact, you do not append a list of 38 0s: you append a **generator** that will **yield** `0` 38 times.  This is not what you want.  However, you can change can change `mb.append(0 for x in range(38))` to

```
mb.append([0 for x in range(38)]) 
# note the [] surrounding the original generator expression!  This turns it
# into a list comprehension.
```

or, more simply (thanks to @John for pointing this out in the comments)

```
mb.append([0] * 38)
```

Comment: Or `mb.extend([0]*38)`, but does that fix the OP's problem?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Oops, I didn't realize the OP actually wanted to append a list of 0s.  Silly me.

Comment: Doesn't that create a list with 1 element which contains 38 times 0? I think you need to use `.extend()`

Comment: @AaronDigulla, no it contains a list with 38 elements each of which is 0. Multiplying a list repeats the elements in the list it doesn't change the actual elements.

Comment: @Duncan: That's wrong. I tried to the code above both on Python2 and 3 and I always get len(mb) == 1.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Was I misinterpreting the OP?  I thought he wanted to append a single item--a list--with 38 `0`s?  You changed my code to add 38 elements to his list.

Comment: I'm rolling the answer back; I think the OP actually wants to append a single list with 38 elements, not append 38 elements to his original list.  Feel free to roll it back again if it turns out I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies, I was looking to add a list of 38 zero elements.  I am still uncertain as to this movement from generator to list comprehension if someone can offer an answer or effective reading material.

Comment: @Robert  The terms are kind of hard to get your head around at first.  A "list comprehension" creates a list, so you can do regular list-y things with it: index, append, etc.  A "generator expression" creates a generator, which you can't index or anything.  You can do a for loop on it, and it will only return (actually, _yield_) the items **as you need them**.  Here's a good answer about iterables in general: http://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/1612701

Answer (score 5):

You should do this instead:

```
mb.extend([0]*38)
```

That way you are appending 38 zeros, rather than appending a single generator expression given by `range()` (n.b. in Python 2 that gave a list instead).

And using extend instead of append makes the list longer by 38 instead of making it longer by 1 and having the 1 new element be a list of 38 zeros.